# Yii has_many relation failed - Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, yii, relationship

I did a lot of HAS_MANY relations but.. This time, it doesn't want to work and I can't figure out why.

I have two models :

`Contest (id, name)` and `MpContest (id, contest_id).`

In my DB, I created the Foreign and Primary keys.

In contest class :

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'mpContests' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MpContest', 'contest_id'),       
    );
}
```

In MpContest class :

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'contest' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Contest', 'contest_id'),
        'contestType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ContestType', 'contest_type'),
    );
}
```

When I try to get relative MpContest from a Contest I get an error.

I try to do this :

```
$mpContests = $this->mpContests;
```

And I get that :

```
CDbCommand n'a pas pu exécuter la commande SQL : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mpContests.contest_id' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `mpContests`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `mpContests`.`name` AS `t1_c1`, `mpContests`.`date_start` AS `t1_c2`, `mpContests`.`date_end` AS `t1_c3`, `mpContests`.`date_start_post` AS `t1_c4`, `mpContests`.`date_end_post` AS `t1_c5` FROM `contest` `mpContests` WHERE (`mpContests`.`contest_id`=:ypl0). Bound with :ypl0='1'
```

I also tried to add 'index' => 'id' in relation but.. Nothing change.

What's wrong ?

Comment: In which file are u trying to make the call "$mpContests = $this->mpContests;"

Comment: I try to call this in Contest model..

Answer (score 0):

Omg ! I found out why it did not want to work..

I  misspelled the table name in MpContest class..

This is my fault. Sorry for my thoughtlessness, maybe someone else will have the same issue.